# how can i store the value that i select from drop down and checkbox in the hidden filed?

Tags: javascript, php, html

[image]

[image]

```js
<script>
       
    var mainlist=document.form.seleField;
    //var valuelist=document.form.seleValue
    //var value=new Array();
    
    var parent = document.getElementById("id1");
    var value=[]
    
    
    value[0]=""
    value[1]=["Monthly|M", "Bi-Weekly|BW", "Weekly|W", "Daily|D"]
    value[2]=["Monday|1", "Tuesday|2", "Wednesday|3", "Thursday|4", "Friday|5", "Saturday|6", "Sunday|7"]
    value[3]=["> 100|100","> 300|300", "> 500|500", "> 700|700", "> 1000|1000", "> 1500|1500", "> 2000|2000" , "> 5000|5000"]
    
    /*    function updatevalue(selectedvaluegroup){
        valuelist.options.length=0
        if (selectedvaluegroup>0){
            for (i=0; i<value[selectedvaluegroup].length; i++)
            valuelist.options[valuelist.options.length]=new Option(value[selectedvaluegroup][i].split("|")[0],
            value[selectedvaluegroup][i].split("|")[1])
        }
    }            
*/



    function updatevalue(selectedvaluegroup){
        parent.innerHTML = "";
        if(selectedvaluegroup ==2){

            for (var i=0; i<value[selectedvaluegroup].length; i++){
                var chkbox = document.createElement("input");
                chkbox.type = "checkbox";
                chkbox.name = "day[]";
                chkbox.value = value[selectedvaluegroup][i].split("|")[1];
                parent.appendChild(chkbox);
                var text = document.createElement("span");
                text.innerHTML = value[selectedvaluegroup][i].split("|")[0];
                parent.appendChild(text);
                
                
            }
        }
        
        else if(selectedvaluegroup > 0){
                
                var select = document.createElement("select");
                parent.appendChild(select);
                for ( i=0; i<value[selectedvaluegroup].length; i++){
                var option = document.createElement("option");
                option.value = value[selectedvaluegroup][i].split("|")[1];
                option.text = value[selectedvaluegroup][i].split("|")[0];
                select.add(option);
            }
        }
        
        
    }
    
</script>
```

```html
<table border="0" width="100%">  
<!-- START ADD FORM -->
<form name="form" action="<?$PHP_SELF?>" method="post" onsubmit="return chkField.exec();">

    <tr bgcolor="#ffffff">
        <td>
            <input id="txtSupplierNo" name="txtSupplierNo" size="6" maxlength="6" class="txbDisplay" tabindex="<?=$tabindex++?>" value="<?=$_GET['primaryID']?>" readOnly> 
        </td>

        <td>
            <input id="txtSupplier" name="txtSupplier" type="text" size = "60" class="txbDisplay" tabindex="<?=$tabindex++?>" value="<?=$objSupp->Supplier?>" readOnly> 
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#3399CC">
        <td class="tfvNormal" id="lblField">Criteria</td>
        <td class="tfvNormal" id="lblValue" colspan="3">Parameter</td>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#ffffff">

        <td>
            <select class='selectBox' name="seleField" id="seleField" onChange="updatevalue(this.selectedIndex)" tabindex="<?=++$tabindex?>">
                <option value="">select a rule</option>
                <option value="OrderFrequency">Order Frequency</option>
                <option value="OrderDay">Order Day</option>
                <option value="MinimumOrder">Minimum Order Amount</option>
            </select>                                    
        </td>
        <td>
            <!--<select class='selectBox' name="seleValue" id="seleValue"  tabindex="<//?=++$tabindex?>"></select>-->
            <div id="id1">
            
            </div>
        </td>
        <td align="center" colspan="2">
            
            <input type="image" src="../../../image/add.gif" name="buttSubmit" id="buttSubmit" value="Add" style="cursor: hand;" onClick="MM_showHideLayers('Layer1','','show')" alt="Add Records" <?=$Permission?> >    
            
        </td>
    </tr>
    
</form>
<!-- END ADD FORM -->
```

i have a problem to get the data and store in database. 
i have two select options which are dropdown and checkbox. 
i use javascript to make the checkbox and only checkbox selection can store the data in the database.

```js
if (($_POST['buttSubmit_x'] >= 0) && ($_POST['seleField'])){

    $Field = trim($_POST['seleField']);
    $Value = trim($_POST['seleValue']);
    $Value = '';
    foreach($_POST['day'] as $selected){
        $Value .= trim($selected) . "|";
    }
    $SupplierNo = $_POST['txtSupplierNo'];
    $Supplier = $_POST['txtSupplier'];
    $CreateUser = $_SESSION['userID'];
    $ModifyUser = $_SESSION['userID'];
    $CreateDate = date("Y-m-j");
    $CreateTime = date("H:i:s");

    if($Field != 'OrderDay'){
        $objchEx = SQL_QUERY("SELECT * FROM SupplierEx WHERE Field='$Field' and SupplierNo='$SupplierNo'");
        if($objchEx->Value && $Value <> $objchEx->Value){
            $chkPara = 1;
            echo"<script>";
            echo"alert('Duplicate $Field ! Kindly delete the existing Parameter.');";
            echo"</script>";    
        }
    }


<table border="0" width="100%">  
                        <!-- START ADD FORM -->
                    <form name="form" action="<?$PHP_SELF?>" method="post" onsubmit="return chkField.exec();">

                            <tr bgcolor="#ffffff">
                                <td>
                                    <input id="txtSupplierNo" name="txtSupplierNo" size="6" maxlength="6" class="txbDisplay" tabindex="<?=$tabindex++?>" value="<?=$_GET['primaryID']?>" readOnly> 
                                </td>

                                <td>
                                    <input id="txtSupplier" name="txtSupplier" type="text" size = "60" class="txbDisplay" tabindex="<?=$tabindex++?>" value="<?=$objSupp->Supplier?>" readOnly> 
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr bgcolor="#3399CC">
                                <td class="tfvNormal" id="lblField">Criteria</td>
                                <td class="tfvNormal" id="lblValue" colspan="3">Parameter</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr bgcolor="#ffffff">

                                <td>
                                    <select class='selectBox' name="seleField" id="seleField" onChange="updatevalue(this.selectedIndex)" tabindex="<?=++$tabindex?>">
                                        <option value="">select a rule</option>
                                        <option value="OrderFrequency">Order Frequency</option>
                                        <option value="OrderDay">Order Day</option>
                                        <option value="MinimumOrder">Minimum Order Amount</option>
                                    </select>                                   
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <!--<select class='selectBox' name="seleValue" id="seleValue"  tabindex="<//?=++$tabindex?>"></select>-->
                                    <div id="id1">

                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td align="center" colspan="2">

                                    <input type="image" src="../../../image/add.gif" name="buttSubmit" id="buttSubmit" value="Add" style="cursor: hand;" onClick="MM_showHideLayers('Layer1','','show')" alt="Add Records" <?=$Permission?> >   

                                </td>
                            </tr>

                        </form>
                        <!-- END ADD FORM -->
                        <script>

                            var mainlist=document.form.seleField;
                            //var valuelist=document.form.seleValue
                            //var value=new Array();

                            var parent = document.getElementById("id1");
                            var value=[]


                            value[0]=""
                            value[1]=["Monthly|M", "Bi-Weekly|BW", "Weekly|W", "Daily|D"]
                            value[2]=["Monday|1", "Tuesday|2", "Wednesday|3", "Thursday|4", "Friday|5", "Saturday|6", "Sunday|7"]
                            value[3]=["> 100|100","> 300|300", "> 500|500", "> 700|700", "> 1000|1000", "> 1500|1500", "> 2000|2000" , "> 5000|5000"]




                            function updatevalue(selectedvaluegroup){
                                parent.innerHTML = "";
                                if(selectedvaluegroup ==2){

                                    for (var i=0; i<value[selectedvaluegroup].length; i++){
                                        var chkbox = document.createElement("input");
                                        chkbox.type = "checkbox";
                                        chkbox.name = "day[]";
                                        chkbox.value = value[selectedvaluegroup][i].split("|")[1];
                                        parent.appendChild(chkbox);
                                        var text = document.createElement("span");
                                        text.innerHTML = value[selectedvaluegroup][i].split("|")[0];
                                        parent.appendChild(text);


                                    }
                                }

                                else if(selectedvaluegroup > 0){

                                        var select = document.createElement("select");
                                        parent.appendChild(select);
                                        for ( i=0; i<value[selectedvaluegroup].length; i++){
                                        var option = document.createElement("option");
                                        option.value = value[selectedvaluegroup][i].split("|")[1];
                                        option.text = value[selectedvaluegroup][i].split("|")[0];
                                        select.add(option);
                                    }
                                }


                            }

                        </script>
```

Comment: I tried to copy-paste the code in my local but not able to do it. Can you check you have uploaded the correct code.

Comment: yes i uploaded the correct code, maybe because of the php

Comment: @ShubhamNagota i add a picture so you can see what it is look like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the below example .Hope it helps

```js
var foo = document.getElementById('foo');
var bar = document.getElementById('bar');
var valueBtn = document.getElementById('valueBtn');

foo.addEventListener('change', function () {
    bar.value = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
}, true);

valueBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    console.log(bar.value)
}, true);
```

```html
<select id="foo">
    <option>select option</option>
    <option>a</option>
    <option>b</option>
</select>
<input style="display:none " type="text" id="bar">
<input type="button" id="valueBtn" value="Click and check console">
```